# Is Unpacking a Type Hint Possible? or Its Workarounds?

Tags: python, type-hinting

Is there a way to **unpack** a **tuple type alias**? For example,

```
ResultTypeA = tuple[float, float, dict[str, float]]
ResultTypeB = tuple[*ResultTypeA, str, str]
```

So that `ResultTypeB` evaluates to

- `tuple[float, float, dict[str, float], str, str]`

instead of

- `tuple[tuple[float, float, dict[str, float]], str, str]`

If not possible, what would be a workaround for this?

Comment: Well, I've gone through the docs and tried some methods in interpreter, but it doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: The solution to this is not to use such complex type annotations. Make a proper class with named fields and use inheritance for that. Otherwise, this looks like bad practice to me.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych or a `NamedTuple`, so it's still subclassable, has less runtime overhead and is closer (at least fully compatible and may serve as a drop-in replacement) to author's original intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for may be the new [`typing.TypeVarTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVarTuple) as proposed by [PEP 646](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/). Due to how new it is (Python `3.11+`) and how big of a change this produces, many static type checkers still do not fully support it (see [this](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/12280) `mypy` issue for example).

Maybe [`typing.Unpack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Unpack) is actually more applicable in this case, but again hardly useful so long as type checkers don't support it.

But at a certain point, you should probably ask yourself, if your design is all that good, if your *type annotations* become this complex.

Comment: I guess changing the design is the answer.

Comment: Can you *build* a `TypeVarTuple`, though? I though they were specifically for capturing multiple types (similar to `*args` in a function signature).

Comment: @chepner You may be right. Kind of hard to test at the moment... Maybe just `Unpack` or the `*`-operator is actually more applicable in this case. Unpacking a parameterized `tuple` with `*` works in Python 3.11 but not in 3.10.